# Validating group of fields with jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

Let's say I have a form with email and phone fields and I want to check if at least one them is correct. I mean, I'm ok with user entering valid phone and invalid email. Is there a way to do this using jQuery validation plug-in? (I wasn't able to find a set of options to cover all the cases and ended up coding it by hand)

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin I wrote for validating fields in jQuery which will do what you want rather well.

**Warning:** I genuinely think this is the best solution for your problem, but don't just take my word for it because I can't be objective.

You can get the plugin here: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate-field

To do what you require:

```
$('#email,#phone').validateField({
    notEmpty: function (val) { // if this function returns true, the field must not be empty
        return ($('#email:blank,#phone:blank').size() > 1);
    },
    message: 'Please fill in either the Email or Phone field',
    validateOn: '#email,#phone',
    validateEvent: 'change'
});
```

**Edit:** added `validateOn` and `validateEvent` to make sure the errors on both objects are cleared when one is filled in.

Comment: The next version coming soon will give you the option of adding the error message to an element at the top or bottom of the form. Put the selector in the `errorBlock` option to allow for this.

Comment: Basically, you're doing it manually, jQuery validate can validate blanks declaratively with depends: "#id:blank".

Comment: @synapse, so it can. I've simplified the function accordingly.

Comment: ...and also uploaded a new release which includes the `:empty` selector (unless it's already defined) and the `:valid` selector should you wish to use it.